# MVC Server Side Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foolproof-validation

I am using [Foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Foolproof/RequiredIf.cs) Validation . When calling

> [RequiredIfTrue("CommonUseStatus")]

Foolproof ReqiuredIfAttribute gives System.NullReferenceException.
Because CommonUseInfo haven't got CommonUseStatus property.
How can I use this Attribute in this way?

```
public class FoundationCode : SpatialEntity
{
   public bool CommonUseStatus {get; set;}
   public string FullFoundationCode { get; set; }
   public string ProvinceCode { get; set; }
   public string DistrictCode { get; set; }
   public bool FoundationOwner { get; set; }
   public virtual CommonUseInfo CommonUseInfo { get; set; }
}


public class CommonUseInfo : BaseEntity
{
   public int CommonUseSchool { get; set; }
   **[RequiredIfTrue("CommonUseStatus")]**
   public DateTime CommonUseStartingDate { get; set; }
   **[RequiredIfTrue("CommonUseStatus")]**
   public DateTime CommonUseEndDate { get; set; }
   public virtual FoundationCode FoundationCode { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use this Attribute in this way?

By adding the property you're attempting to reference:

```
public bool CommonUseStatus { get; set; }
```

That way the validator can reference the boolean property to determine whether or not the attribute-decorated property is required.

Comment: FoundatinCode has a CommonUseStatus property. I forgot to add question

Comment: @AliFuat: Mostly a guess since the inner workings of that library are unknown to me, but can you use "FoundationCode.CommonUseStatus" in the attribute?